# select feature in Openlayer is not working, selected feature doesn't highlight?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I manage to search the feature by its attribute..the problem is, it doesn't highlight the feature..
[image: sample result]

A popup will show but the selected feature does not highlight...here's my code below:

```
    this.showparcel = function(getpin){
        for(var f=0;f<layer_agao.features.length;f++) {
                    if(layer_agao.features[f].attributes.newpin === getpin) {
                        featsel = layer_agao.features[f];
                        selectControl.select(featsel);
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        selectControl.unselect(featsel);
                    }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine by using jquery and change `selectControl.select(featsel);` into `selectControl.clickFeature(featsel);` to avoid multiple selection of feature when searching..

Here's the code:

```
$("#forminput").change(function(){
        for (var f = 0; f < layer_agao.features.length; f++) {
            if (layer_agao.features[f].attributes.newpin == this.value) {
                featsel = layer_agao.features[f];
                $("#mybutton").click(function(){
                    selectControl.clickFeature(featsel);
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

It should be placed inside you `init()` function, below is the html markup.

```
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                            <select name="q" class="form-control" id="forminput">
                                <option type="text" value=""><b>Select Land PIN</b></option>
                                {% for getlandpins in query_map %}
                                 <option type="text" value="{{ getlandpins.newpin }}">{{ getlandpins.newpin }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Show Info" id="mybutton">
    </form>
```